# Jquery Datepicker: Can we hide it on iOS and show native iOS datepicker/spinner instead?

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile, datepicker, hide

I am using the datepicker here:

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

It works great on desktop.

However, on the iPhone, I would like to hide it and trigger the native spinner instead.

The kicker is that I had to change the input on the form to:

```
<input type="text">
```

I did this in order to keep it from interfering with Chrome's built-in datepicker when I originally used:

```
<input type="datetime-local">
```

that unfortunately caused the native datepicker on iPhone to disappear because it is now detecting it as a text field.

Ideally, what I am trying to achieve is to use the Jquery datepicker on all browsers, except mobile devices that have their own native datepicker (like the iPhone, for example). However, I must hide the HTML5 datepicker in the process.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could wrap the javascript function calls in if statements based on the OS.

```
var OSName="";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) {OSName="Windows"};
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) {OSName="MacOS"};
```

Maybe call different functions for the date picker depending on OS?

Reference: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/operatin.htm